# Why does a code asking for the largest integer give random outputs?

Tags: c

This is some code to check for and print the greatest integer of the ones provided by user.

```
int a, b, c;

scanf("%d %d %d", &a,&b,&c);

if (a > (b || c )) {
  printf ("%d", a);
} else if (b > (a || c)) {
  printf ("%d", b);
} else {
  printf ("%d", c);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Two things: First, I'm not sure what (b || c) turns into. That's a logical operator. I suppose that would be "TRUE" which means you are asking if a > TRUE.

Comment: Second, why else if (b > (a || c))? You know b > a (I suppose it could be equal, but still). Even if your logic worked the way you wanted, (that is, the a || c part), this will always be true unless a is equal to b.

Answer (score 4):

Conditions are wrong. For example:
Instead of `if (a > (b || c ))` you need `if((a > b) || (a > c))`. (Paranthesis are optional)

Note: You actually mean `&&` and not `||`

---

So what does `a > (b || c )`

`(b || c)` would evaluate to `0` if both `b` and `c` are `0`. Otherwise it evaluates to `1`.

If `a` is greater than the above result, control would enter the condition.

Comment: `a` would only need to be `2` to always be greater than `(b || c)` `:)`